# Monitor cron jobs in real-time

Tags: linux, cron

I have an issue currently where I've got a cron job set to run at midnight each day to reset daily API requests for a service that I run. The job failed recently which caused me a whole bunch of headaches and I've been trying to find a solution to monitor all of my cron jobs so I don't have a situation like this happen again.

I haven't been able to find a sufficient solution however, and in response I am considering creating a platform that allows you to monitor cron jobs, see logs (and past logs), last run date, failure/success of the last run, etc... in real-time and would notify you if your job hasn't completed within a specified window of time or the job failed.

I believe this might be a pain point and a good solution for others as well.

What are you thoughts? Do you think that this would be useful, have any suggestions, or just think this would be a waste of time?

Answer (score 3):

Did you hear about Rundeck? (https://www.rundeck.com/open-source)

It looks like it's exactly what you're looking for.

You install it on a server, and it's like a Web UI for a crontab.
You define jobs you want to run using the Web UI, how often you want them to run and you can see some history of the past executions, their status and their output. You can also see when the next execution will happen.

I think there are also some alerting features to notify you if a job is on failure. I'm not sure if it can notify you based on the job execution time though.

This might be a good fit for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, I am asking myself exactly the same questions ) Definitely you should have created such service already, haven't you? Every backend coder needs this time from time, in theory. I'm surprised this question hasn't received enough activity/voting. I got an answer leading to this though: https://uptimerobot.com/cron-job-monitoring/ that might be a good solution. Need to test it out. It does not seem to be promoted enough, as it's not easy to find. Also there is https://cronitor.io/docs/cron-job-monitoring that has ability to transmit (somewhat limited) telemetry data, +a lot of SDKs to be used from within programming languages.

Comment: As it happens, I was asking the same questions as well, and as a result made an open-source tool: https://github.com/healthchecks/healthchecks